# why i can not use using() in win application c#

Tags: c#

i have a class(WebCamManager) in my win application.i want to use using() statement but dose not accept.
it says in help:"Type Used in a using statement must be implicity convertible to System.IDisposable"

```
 WebCamManager objCamManager ;
using (objCamManager = new WebCamManager())
        {

        }
```

Comment: Does `WebCamManager` implements `IDisposable`?

Comment: Please read all error messages *carefully*. They are there to help. My question for you is why you want to use the class in a `using` statement to begin with?

Comment: Please review what it means to "be implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable".

Answer (score 1):

Because `WebCamManager` doesn't implement `IDisposable` interface. Need more than that?

If `WebCamManager` implements `IDisposable`, only then you'll be able to use the `using` declaration.